# Django crispy form tab

Tags: python, django, forms

I am now studying `Django form`. Right now I am focusing on `crispy form`. 
For now crispy and then after I master the `form` I will move on to `Django Admin form` and `Django admin model form`.

Django 1.10
Python 3.6.0

I am following these tutorials:
https://blog.bixly.com/awesome-forms-django-crispy-forms
http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#
https://godjango.com/29-crispy-forms/

Here are my source code: 
`views.py:`

```
from django.views.generic import FormView
from apps.colors.forms import PersonDetailForm

class ColorStudyView(FormView):
    template_name = 'colors/study.html'
    form_class = PersonDetailForm
    success_url = '/'
```

`forms.py:`

```
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import Tab, TabHolder
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout
from django import forms


class NoFormTagCrispyFormMixin(object):
    @property
    def helper(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_helper'):
            self._helper = FormHelper()
            self._helper.form_tag = False
        return self._helper


class PersonDetailForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    address1 = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    address2 = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    state = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)

    mobile = forms.CharField(max_length=32, required=False)
    home = forms.CharField(max_length=32, required=False)
    office = forms.CharField(max_length=32, required=False)
    twitter = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            TabHolder(
                Tab('Information',
                    'name',
                    'age'
                    ),
                Tab('Address',
                    'address1',
                    'address2',
                    'city',
                    'state'
                ),
                Tab('Contact',
                    'mobile',
                    'home',
                    'office',
                    'twitter',
                )
            )
        )
        self.helper.layout.append(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

`study.html:`

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Study</title>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    {% crispy form %}
    </form>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**Problem:**
Tab does not change.
Am I miss something?
Sorry for very basic level question, but this is my first day with `Django frontend`

Here is my picture. Tab `Address` and `Contact` are not work.

[image]

**Update:**
Zollie solves my problem. Here is my `study.html`

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Study</title>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    {% crispy form %}
    </form>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap-tab.js' %}">  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my filesystem configuration

```
/Users/el/Code/siam-sbrand/static
(siam-sbrand) Sarits-MacBook-Air-2:static el$ ls
admin           django_extensions   img
bootstrap-tab.js    file.txt        js
dist            font            rest_framework
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem when first I wanted to use the Tabs in crispy forms. The documentation is quite weak unfortunately for this package.

The answer on why TabHolder and Tabs are not working is, because you have to include jquery and javascript in your html template head. Also, you have to download bootstrap-tab.js and put it in your 'static' folder in the bootstrap subfolder ie., and you also have to include the path to it in your html .

So, it is not enough if you just include Bootstrap or bootstrap.css in the html head.
Here is an example how it should look like:

```
  <head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js' %}">  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Since my question is very old now. I have to dig my directories and start studying again. I will get back to you as fast as I can

Comment: Hi @Sarit, Just a small correction on your update: in your updated html, the <script> links should go in the <head> to the top.
The <title> and <form> should be in the <body> of the html. Probably you edited that fast and that's why you mixed it a litlle.
Thank you! ;)

Comment: This is new knowledge for me. My example in the company I have seen only <script> in the bottom. I will follow your best practice. Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, I answered you a bit too fast too. The <title> of course stays in the <head> of the html also. The <form> goes in the <body>. ;) (it was early in the morning here :) ) 
I mean:
<body>
    {% block content %}
    <h1>New Person Form</h1>
    {% crispy form %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>

Comment: ...and in the <head> there goes the <link> to css files, <title> and so on.... Then the <scripts>. First the jquery then javascripts. Just to leave it clear for other readers.;)

Comment: You are so kind. How can I get in touch with you?

Comment: Hi @Sarit, thank you for your kind words! I am sorry I’m not available at the moment, that’s why I deliberately do not provide contact info here. Probably a bit later I will. Anyway, we'll check on each other later, since as I see you are working quite a lot with Django/Python too.

Answer (score 0):

Check these things:

1. In settings.py you should have `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'`
2. In your static files you should have a bootstrap-tab.js

Comment: First one I had it already. But the second one I don't have it. So the the problem comes from `bootstrap-tab.js` is missing from my system

Comment: I did collectstatic and both `bootstrap3` and `bootstrap4` in settings.py. No effect at all

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is old and solved, I find it might be worthwhile to add some more observations: I came across the problem and found another cause.

First, I checked and confirmed that I had included the .js files as mentioned in the accepted answer. But the tab still did not work.

I found some bootstrap tab examples, such as https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/components/tabs/. And I concluded that, to make tab work, one should make sure there is a one-to-one relationship between the href attr of the 'tab header' and the id attr of the 'tab body'. Like this:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home"
      aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile"
      aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact"
      aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">A Tab</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">B tab</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">C tab</div>
</div>
```

Note: pay attention to the href attrs of 'a' elements and the id attrs of 'div' elements.

I did some experimentation and concluded that: once related .js and other files are imported and href and id attrs are properly set, the tab would work.

Now the problem became "how to make crispy set them properly".

I checked following files:
1. /root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/crispy_forms/bootstrap.py

```py
class Tab(Container):
    """
    Tab object. It wraps fields in a div whose default class is "tab-pane" and
    takes a name as first argument. Example::

        Tab('tab_name', 'form_field_1', 'form_field_2', 'form_field_3')
    """
    css_class = 'tab-pane'
    link_template = '%s/layout/tab-link.html'

    def render_link(self, template_pack=TEMPLATE_PACK, **kwargs):
        """
        Render the link for the tab-pane. It must be called after render so css_class is updated
        with active if needed.
        """
        link_template = self.link_template % template_pack
        return render_to_string(link_template, {'link': self})
```

2. /root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap3/layout/tab-link.html

```html
<li class="tab-pane{% if 'active' in link.css_class %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#{{ link.css_id }}" data-toggle="tab">{{ link.name|capfirst }}{% if tab.errors %}!{% endif %}</a></li>
```

I noticed the css_id attr. And I guessed that if one set 'css_id' properly, maybe crispy would do the rest. I tried. And it worked like a charm.

Maybe crispy documentation needs some improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you- like me- search for answer why this solution doesn't work for you, check if you are using bootstrap 4. To my knowledge tabs from crispy don't work on 5 at least for now.